# How to create and check a subdirectory in the Application Bundle

Tags: ios, nsbundle, subdirectory

i have create a new subdirectory in my application bundle. This i have done in the xcode environment.

target -> copy bundle resources

now add a new folder

create folder references for any added folders

how can i check that the folder is created in the application bundle

Thank you

Answer (score 18):

To check the folder/directory has been created inside your application bundle (.app), right click on your .app file and select "Show Package Contents". Now check if folder/directory appears in your .app file.

As a side note, an easier way to add a folder/directory to your .app bundle is to add "Folder" instead of "Group" in your Xcode project. For example, lets say you have a bunch of files inside /HTML directory. Drag and Drop this /HTML directory in your Xcode project. Xcode will present a dialog with options like, "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)", "Create groups for any added folders", and "Create folder references for any added folders". Choose "Create folder references for any added folders" in this dialog. As a result, you'll see a blue group folder, instead of the usual yellow group folder for your /HTML directory (in your Xcode project), and Building the .app will create /HTML folder inside your .app bundle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brava, exactly what I needed. @Pinky I think you should accept this one as the answer.

Comment: You have no idea how much you have helped me. Although this question was about something else but I got to know the difference between a "Group" and a "Folder". And that was the reason why my file path was never getting me to the file, because it was in a group(./file) and not a folder(./folder/file) while my path was like the latter.